# MariaDB/MySQL: Dump current transaction data

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Suppose, I have a transaction that contains some delete, insert and update queries with a lot of select-joins and values inferred from other tables. Sometimes even outright math inside queries. This makes forensics very hard, but reengineering the queries isn't going to happen any time soon.

How can I, within the transaction, see (or, preferably, dump) the actual data (in tables and rows) that is being changed within the transaction before committing it?

In short, I want a transaction delta.

I use MariaDB 10.3.23

Comment: You may сreate a bunch of triggers which will fix state before and after for each table in interest. The trigger must look for user-defined variable as dumping flag. When you need to fix states you add predefined UDV with predefined name then execute your transaction. And triggers saves the data you're interested in into some debugging table(s). Of course this will degrade your system performance seriously.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! This is not something you'll be wanting to experiment with on PROD. If you have (a) test system(s), that's great. You might, though, want to make use of the `SLEEP()` function to simulate long running queries if your sample dbs don't have many records - triggers though are the way to go!

Comment: We have too many records in the base to pull something like this.